# Compare two files based on fields

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have two UNIX files with below data. I have to compare field 1, field 2 and field 3 of file 1 with file 2 and if that matches I have to check whether the field 5 in file 1 matches with field 5 of file 2 , if it does not match I have to print it from file 1 otherwise just ignore.

file 1

```
A|B|C|1|D|

A|B|D|1|D|

A|B|E|1|D|

A|B|F|1|D|
```

file 2

```
A|B|Z|1|D|

A|B|C|1|x|

A|B|D|1|y|

A|B|E|1|D|
```

So the result should be 
    A|B|C|1|D|

```
A|B|D|1|D|
```

Comment: why not `A|B|C|1|D` ? satisfies the conditions "A,B,C" matches and "D!=x"

Comment: This Q is unclear and incomplete.  Please specify the field separator and the file comparison method (i.e. compare *file1,line1,fields{1,2,3,5}`* to *file2,line1,fields{1,2,3,5}`*, or something else).  Include the code have you've written to solve this problem.

Comment: As mentioned in the question the field separator is |.
The 1st,2nd and 3rd field of file1 are compared with the 1st,2nd and 3rd of file2 and if it matches then we compare the 5th field of both the files. If the 5th field is different the output should be the 1st,2nd and 3rd field of file1 otherwise it should just carry on to check the other lines.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

This for matching fields 1,2,3,5

```
$ awk -F'|' '{k=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $5} NR==FNR{a[k];next} k in a' file2 file1

A|B|E|1|D|
```

your question was different, however, the results doesn't match yours and you need to explain why one of the records shouldn't be printed

```
$ awk -F'|' '{k=$1 FS $2 FS $3} 
     NR==FNR {a[k]=$5; next} 
     k in a && a[k]!=$5' file2 file1

A|B|C|1|D|
A|B|D|1|D|
```

Comment: Both should be in the result
A|B|C|1|D|
A|B|D|1|D|

Comment: Could you please explain the answer.